# how to access a locally defined list (Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to check user-input against the list I created inside a function. What is the best way to pass variables between functions without using globals?

```
def counter():
    integers = []
    x = 0
    while x < 100:
        x = x + 1
        integers.append (x)
        #print integers
    return

integers_global = counter () 
print integers_global
speed = int (raw_input ("what is the speed of an unladen swallow in km/h (enter a number): "))
if speed in integers_global:
    print "the speed of the swallow is equal to", speed, "km/h"
else:
    print "the speed of the swallow is equal to %r" %speed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to pass variables between functions without using
>   globals?

**arguments** to get values **into** functions, **return values** to get them out.  So in your case you only have the second problem to solve, and should just change the bare `return` (which returns a value of `None`) into `return integers` (which returns the result value you **care** about!-).

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing to do is to `return` the list you created. 
Just modify the return statement to

```
 return integers
```

at the end of your `counter()` function.

If you were using those in a class and wanted `integers` to be used many times or across different methods for some reason, you could also make it a data attribute like `self.integers` but this is not the case here.